# Modificar valor de un DataFrame con iterrows()

Tags: python, bucles

Quiero modificar un DataFrame con un loop, y me sale.
Lo que realmente quiero hacer es que en la columna de precio se modifique el valor de "$5000,00" a "5000.00". Intente de la siguiente manera:

```
for index,row in dfTest.iterrows():
    if(row["Precio Anterior"].find("$")!= -1):

        row["Precio Anterior"] = row["Precio Anterior"].replace("$", "")
        row["Precio Anterior"] = row["Precio Anterior"].replace(",", ".")
        row["Precio Anterior"] = float(row["Precio Anterior"])
```

Se agradece cualquier tipo de ayuda. 
Saludos

Comment: `dfTest["Precio Anterior"] = dfTest["Precio Anterior"].str.replace("$", "").str.replace(",",".").astype(float)`

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias, Si le saco el astype(float), hace todo lo que tiene que hacer menos convertir el valor en float. me tira este error, `'ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'desde\xa0700.00desde''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre que se pueda, en lugar de iterar por las filas, conviene usar las operaciones vectoriales que Pandas proporciona.

En caso de que una columna contenga cadenas, el operador `.str` sobre esa columna te devuelve un objeto sobre el cual hacer una operación vectorial, que significa que opera sobre todas las filas "a la vez", devolviéndote una nueva columna con los resultados.

En un comentario sugería usar `.str.replace()` para reemplazar un carácter por otro en la columna entera. Este enfoque no sirvió para el caso planteado porque hay celdas en la columna que no contienen únicamente el precio, sino también algún texto como "desde".

Planteo entonces otra posibilidad más potente. Mediante `.str.extract()` se puede usar una expresión regular con un grupo de captura para extraer lo que es el precio. En este caso consideraré un precio válido cualquier secuencia de caracteres compuesta por dígitos, punto o coma, es decir, la expresión regular `([\d,\.]+)` Al resultado del `extract()`, que será otra columna de cadenas, se le puede aplicar `.str.replace()` para cambiar las comas por puntos y finalmente un `.astype(float)` para convertir a flotante el resultado.

Por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
precios = ["$23,12", "desde $100,30", "$100.22", "$44,15"]

df = pd.DataFrame(precios, columns=["Precio Anterior"])
```

---

```
  Precio Anterior
0          $23,12
1   desde $100,30
2         $100.22
3          $44,15
```

Sobre ese dataframe de ejemplo hacemos:

```
df["Precio Anterior"] = (df["Precio Anterior"]
                         .str.extract(r"([\d,\.]+)", expand=False)
                         .str.replace(",", ".")
                         .astype(float))
```

y sale:

```
   Precio Anterior
0            23.12
1           100.30
2           100.22
3            44.15
```

Comment: Increible, de todos tus comentarios siempre aprendo algo nuevo, y la explicación es excelente. muchas gracias