# Cargar datos en columnas de un DataFrame Python

Tags: python, bucles

estoy intentando insertar datos de un DataFrame, pero no puedo. Me gustaria saber porque al finalizar el for, las columnas "Precio nuevo" y "Precio viejo" quedan en 0.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     spliting = row["Precio Viejo/Nuevo"].split('$')
     if(len(spliting) == 3):
         row["Precio Nuevo"] = spliting[2]
     else:
         row["Precio Nuevo"] = spliting[1]
     row["Precio Viejo"] = spliting[1]
```

luego hago

```
df["Precio Nuevo]
```

y muestra 0

Comment: Tu código está un poco mal formateado, ¿puedes editar la pregunta y poner bien el sangrado o _indentacion_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estás usando `pandas` y de acuerdo a las recomendaciones que se te hicieron también en esta respuesta [Modificar valor de un DataFrame con iterrows()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251385/modificar-valor-de-un-dataframe-con-iterrows), hay dos métodos de la **API** que permiten lograr lo que se busca:

[pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) y [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) (ambas en inglés) en tal sentido, te sugiero que siempre coloques la forma de los datos, porque dependiendo de ello, se condiciona el patrón ha emplear, esto también incide en la calidad de la respuesta que obtendrás, no obstante en este caso concreto, como son precios, se pueden asumir algunos patrones sin que eso incida mucho en el resultado final.

De lo expuesto, el código sería el siguiente con sus respectivos reportes y comentarios:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["$1$2.7","3.5$4","$5 $6"], columns=["Precio Viejo/Nuevo"])
print(df)
#   Precio Viejo/Nuevo
# 0             $1$2.7
# 1              3.5$4
# 2              $5 $6


# se remueve el "$" y se reemplaza por ' '
# para que sea asignado a una variable a
# luego se procede a efectuar un split
a = df['Precio Viejo/Nuevo'].str.replace('$',' ')
separar_precios = a.str.split(n=1, expand=True)


print(separar_precios)
#      0    1
# 0    1  2.7
# 1  3.5    4
# 2    5    6


# se crean las columnas Precio Nuevo y Precio Viejo
# y se asigna los valores previamente obtenidos
df["Precio Nuevo"] = separar_precios[1]
df["Precio Viejo"] = separar_precios[0]


# Resultado Final
print(df)
#  Precio Viejo/Nuevo Precio Nuevo Precio Viejo
# 0             $1$2.7          2.7            1
# 1              3.5$4            4          3.5
# 2              $5 $6            6            5
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que ocurre es con `row["Precio Nuevo"]` solo estás actualizando el valor recibido del iterador `df.iterrows()`,  de ninguna manera estás modificando el valor en la fila del `dataframe` original. Lo que podrías hacer, es algo como esto:

```
df.loc[index, 'Precio Nuevo'] = <nuevo valor>
```